# Prove that R is a field ↔ The only ideals in R are R(0) and (0).

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rings and ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101157/rings-and-ideals)

The question is the title, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: PS: The statement is false as given: the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices over a field are simple (so the only ideals are $(0)$ and the entire ring)  but they are not even a division ring. You should (i) put the question in the body, not just the title; and (ii) put **all the hypothesis** in the question. This problem almost certainly included the words "commutative" and "with unity" somewhere along the line.

Comment: I would think the definition of a ring does not [almost certainly not require unity]. $\;$

Answer (score 6):

Below is a proof that a *commutative ring* $R$ is a field iff its only ideals are $R$ and $(0)$:

Suppose first that $R$ is a field. Then any nonzero ideal $I$ must contain $1$, as for any $0\neq x\in I$ it must contain $x^{-1}x=1$, hence contains $r\cdot1=r$ for any $r\in R$ so $R\subseteq I$. By definition $I\subseteq R$, so $I=R$. Suppose instead that $R$ is *not* a field. Then we have some nonzero element $x\in R$ which has no inverse, so $(x)=\{rx | r\in R\}$ is not $(0)$ and cannot contain $1$ (as this would mean we have some $r\in R$ such that $rx=1$, and so since $R$ is commutative $rx=xr=1$ hence $x^{-1}=r$) so is not $R$. Thus $R$ is a field iff its only ideals are $R$ and $(0)$.

Note that $R$ may or may not be considered an ideal of $R$, depending on convention. Some authors reserve the term "ideal" for *proper* ideals, that is ideals which are not the whole ring. This convention is typical among authors who require rings to have $1\neq 0$, as this means that the trivial ring $R/R$ is not a ring under their definition.

Comment: Your answer implicitly assumes that R contains identity when you claim that (x) doesn't contain 1 hence is not R. This is not clear at all as to why not containing 1 means (x) is not R unless R is known to contain 1.