# Every field is a local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, local-rings

I have a short question about a local ring. I just saw the concept and looked something up on the internet.

> I wonderdered if it is true that every field is a local ring?

Because ${0}$ is the only maximal ideal. I'm not sure, because i can't prove that if $R$ is a field then only ${0}$ and $R$ are ideals.

Comment: Yes, every field is a local ring.

Comment: can you maybe explain why?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101158/prove-that-r-is-a-field-%E2%86%94-the-only-ideals-in-r-are-r0-and-0).

Comment: @mathmath Because a ring is local preciesely when it has a unique maximal ideal and a field has a unique maximal ideal.  What else is there to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $R$ is a field and $I\ne\{0\}$ is an ideal, take $r\in I$, $r\ne0$. Then
$$
1=rr^{-1}\in I
$$
so $I=R$.

More generally, a commutative ring $R$ is local if and only if the set of noninvertible elements of $R$ is an ideal.