# Find all ideals of $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb Q$ be the set of all rational numbers. I would like to know what the ideal for $\mathbb Q$ as ring is. I think the ideal of $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb Q$, Am I right?

Comment: We can't say _the_ ideal since $\{0\}$ is also an ideal.

Comment: Hint:  $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field.

Comment: A much more interesting question is: What are the subrings of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: See also this question: [A ring is a field iff the only ideals are (0) and (1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101157/a-ring-is-a-field-iff-the-only-ideals-are-0-and-1)

Answer (score 6):

An ideal must enjoy the property that if you multiply any of its members by any rational number, what you get is still in the ideal.  But if a member $x$ of the supposed ideal is not $0$, then it's easy to show that if you take all products of $x$ with rational numbers, the set that you get, which is $\{xy:y\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, is all of $\mathbb{Q}$.  So nothing smaller than $\mathbb{Q}$ can be an ideal in this ring, except $\{0\}$.

Here's the proof: suppose $w$ is *any* member of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Then $w/x$ is rational.  So $w/x$ is the value of $y$ that will serve.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$ with unity
s.t.   $1 \in I$.

We have $q \in \mathbb{Q}
\Rightarrow q = 1•q  ∈ I
\Rightarrow \mathbb{Q} ⊆ I 
\Rightarrow \mathbb{Q} = I$

Hence $\mathbb{Q}$ has only two ideals i.e, $\mathbb{Q}$ itself and $\{0\}$.