# Ideals in a real/complex number field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Considering a real or complex number field (with traditional addition and multiplication) I see no ideals besides $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{ 0\}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and $\{ 0 + 0i\}$.

Quick web search gave no satisfactory results. Yet I believe this couldn't be considered trivial, could it?

I am contemplating quite a few ideas for example looking for possible kernels of homomorphisms. Maybe you could give some references? Ideally I'd love to figure out even multiple different proofs for this.

Comment: A related result to those in the answers is that every homomorphism of fields is injective (assuming we make the usual requirement that $\varphi(1)\ne\varphi(0)$ when $\varphi$ is a homomorphism of fields - else the zero map would be the one exception).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fields only have the two obvious ideals. That is because in a field, every non-zero element is invertible, and invertible elements generate the entire ring as ideals.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are getting confused by the terminolgy. Neither ${\mathbb R}$ nor ${\mathbb C}$ is a number field. A number field is a subfield of ${\mathbb C}$ which is a finite extension of ${\mathbb Q}$, such as ${\mathbb Q}(i)$ or ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

As others have pointed out, fields only have two ideals. But every number field $K$ has a ring of integers $D$ (which is the subring of the algebraic integers in the field), and it is customary within the algebraic number theory community to refer to ideals of $D$ as ideals of the number field. To further complicate matters, there are *fractional ideals*, which are finitely generated $D$-submodules $M$ of $K$ with the property that $cM \le K$ for some $c \in D$, and these are sometimes referred to simply as ideals.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification regarding the terminology. None of the subjects are presented in English to me so I obviously have some work to do.

Answer (score 2):

It is known that a ring $R$ is a field iff it contains only trivial ideals, i.e., the only ideals in $R$ are $\{0\}$ and $R$ itself. See, e.g., [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101206/15768).

Comment: You need the ring to be commutative. Division rings also don't have non-trivial two-sided ideals.

Comment: Thanks for your remark and a very interesting reference.