# Prove that R is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

I have a question:
Let R be an integral domain, if the only ideals are the trivial ideals, prove that R is a field.

So my proof for this was;

Let $a\in R$ be a non-zero element.
Since we have that the only ideals are $(0)$ and $(1)$ we have that $a$ cannot be in $(0)$
since it's non-zero.
Since $a$ isn't in $(0)$, it has to be in $(1)$ which implies that $a$ is a multiple of $1$ for some $b$ i.e. $ab = 1$

But this implies that $a$ is a unit so therefore $R$ is a field.

My professor told me there's a better way of doing this. Using the following theorem:
Let $R$ be a ring that is commutative with identity and let $M$ be an ideal in $R$. Then $M$ is maximal iff $R/M$ is a field.

Personally, I have no idea how to use this theorem for this proof. It's obvious that $(0)$ is maximal so that means $R/(0)$ is a field. How do I go about showing R is a field using this?

Comment: What are the elements of $R / (0)$ ?

Comment: $R/(0)\cong R$.

Comment: I'm not sure the professor's way is "better". What you're giving is essentially the proof of the theorem he wants you to appeal to. (Though you should write "$1$ is a multiple of $a$" rather than "$a$ is a multiple of $1$").

Comment: It's a matter of taste. I don't think that using $M$ maximal $\Rightarrow R/M$ is a field is a better way to do it.

Comment: Ahh, I feel very silly for asking something that was very obvious. I did over think this, thanks everyone!

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101157/a-ring-is-a-field-iff-the-only-ideals-are-0-and-1) but I guess not a duplicate since this is essentially a proof verification/strategy question.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't valid as written: Since $a \in (1)$, it means that $a$ is a multiple of $1$, so that there exists $b \in R$ such that

$$a = 1 \cdot b$$

But we already knew that, since we can *always* choose $b = a$, so this doesn't tell us anything new. In general, $(1) = R$ always.

---

For a different way to proceed, consider the ideal $(a)$. You've already noted that $(a) \ne (0)$, so $(a) = (1)$. Now use this statement to find an inverse of $a$.

Alternatively, to use the theorem that your professor mentioned, note that $(0)$ is maximal, so that $R/(0)$ is a field; but $R/(0)$ is isomorphic to $R$.

Comment: Ah, I rushed my proof quickly so I did make a mistake while writing this out. But my proof is pretty much identical to yours. Thank you!