# If $A$ is a commutative ring with unity, and let $a \in A$ be a nonzero element, is $\langle a \rangle$ necessarily an ideal of $A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

My question comes from the top solution of [A ring is a field iff the only ideals are $(0)$ and $(1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101157/a-ring-is-a-field-iff-the-only-ideals-are-0-and-1). Here, at the end the solver states that $\langle a \rangle$ is automatically an ideal of $A$. Why is that?

Comment: This is one of many things in higher mathematics that is completely straightforward provided you have fully grasped the definitions involved.  If you know what an ideal is and what $\langle a \rangle$ means, you have some routine checking to do.  Which part, if any, is troubling you?

Comment: An ideal $I$ of $A$ is an additive subgroup of $A$ such that $rI \subseteq I$ for all $r \in A$. I get why $\langle a \rangle$ is an additive subgroup of $A$ but I don't understand how the solver knows it also satisfies $r\langle a \rangle \subseteq \langle a \rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just learned that $(a)$ represents the ideal generated by $a$ and not a subgroup. In other words, $$(a):=\{ra:r\in A\}.$$ After noting this, the solution makes sense.

Comment: +1 for doing the research to answer your own question. Next time do the research first, save this site for more interesting things.

Comment: I wanted to ask this question on the original solution, but I didn't have enough points to be able to leave comments.