# Ideals of the real numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

What would be the ideals of the real numbers?

I have to figure out the ideals of a ring R, which is a product of integers and reals like so:

$R = \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Are the ideals simply 0 and $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I am going to close this as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/101157/29335 unless you want to change the question to ask about the ring $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb R\times \mathbb Z$. To answer your last question: yes.

Comment: @rschwieb At a second thought I think your link is better for closing this as a duplicate.

Comment: @user26857 All bases are covered as it is, probably don't need to overoptimize now.

Comment: The explanation for how a ring is a field iff its only ideals are 0 and itself is very helpful, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $R$ and $S$ are rings with unity, then the ideals of $R\times S$ are of the form $I\times J$ where $I$ is an ideal of $R$ and $J$ is an ideal of $S$. Since the product of two rings with unity is a ring with unity, ideals of $R\times S\times T$ with $R$, $S$, $T$ all unital rings will be of the form $I\times J\times K$ where $I$, $J$, and $K$ are ideals of $R$, $S$, and $T$, respectively. $\Bbb R$ is a field, so the only ideals are $(0)$ and $\Bbb R$. Then it remains to classify ideals of $\Bbb Z$.