# Is $\mathbb{Z}$ an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have to decide whether or not $\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$.

My attempt:

$\exists q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $z\in\mathbb{Z} $ such that $qz\notin\mathbb{Z}$, for example for $q=\frac{1}{2}, z=1$.

Thus, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$, but not its ideal.

Am I right?

Comment: How do you know that $\exists q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $z\in\mathbb{Q} $ such that $qz\notin\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $z\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: The "for example" part you added makes it much better.

Comment: @GEdgar Already done.

Comment: Now, it is correct. Where's the doubt?

Comment: Also, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field. Does that mean anything to you? (It mightn't; this isn't a rhetorical question.)

Comment: @AnotherUser Wanted to be sure if I got it right.

Comment: @FirdousAhmadMala Do you know what "simple rings" are ? . A field is a simple ring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your demonstration that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$ is sufficient, since it shows that $\mathbb{Z}$ does not "absorb" multiplication by $\mathbb{Q}$; in fact, it spills out to the entirety of $\mathbb{Q}$.

It is also enough to observe that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field; fields only have two ideals—the trivial zero ring and the entire field. (In fact, the implication goes both ways—if a commutative ring has only two ideals, it is a field. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101157/a-commutative-ring-is-a-field-iff-the-only-ideals-are-0-and-1) on this site, for example.)

Comment: egreg: Thanks for the edit, totally missed that.